# Can I use Ember-cli ember-validations release 0.0.0

Tags: ember-cli, ember-validations

https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations/releases

Currently we have only alpha releases and Since 2.0.0 is not out which might take time as I see there are blocker issues for the release.

I am not sure if I can use 0.0.0 will it have any breaking changes ?

what does 0.0.0 mean here is it Initial stable version which supports ember-cli
I think 0.0.0 is an initial version which just is empty addon.

Since ember-validations does not even have a beta , it cannot be used in production.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 1.0.0 is not an ember-addon

Answer (score 0):

we cannot use 0.0.0 it is not a Ember-cli addon
we should just include js file (self executing js )and use it 
ember-validations can be used once 2.0.0 is out currently it has only alpha releases.